# Invariance of domain theorem with differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

I have studied the invariance of domain theorem

> Given a continuous injection $f:U→\mathbb{R}^n$ where U is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f$ is an open map.

with proof by using Brouwer fixed point theorem.

However, there is an easier proof if $f$ is continuous differentiable.

So I want to ask, is there an easier proof (than Brouwer fixed point theorem) when $f$ is differentiable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trying. Please let me know if it is wrong.

Suppose $f$ is continuous differentiable and injective. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism over $f(U)$. By applying the inverse mapping theorem we get that 
$h=f^{-1}|f(U)$  is also differentiable, and onto over $U$. Suppose now $f(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, $m<n$.  By using Sard's Theorem we can ensure that 
$h(f(U))=U$  has zero measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which can not happens since $U$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}^n$.